# Getting documents having minimum value for a given field

Tags: elasticsearch

My document structure is as below:

```
{'_id': 1, '_type': '2017-01-01',...}  --- (1)
{'_id': 1, '_type': '2017-01-02',...}  --- (2)
{'_id': 2, '_type': '2017-01-01',...}  --- (3)
{'_id': 2, '_type': '2017-01-02',...}  --- (4)
```

Each id can belong to different types (which are dates here). The aim is to get documents matching given id list having minimum value of _type.

So for an input of id=[1,2], documents 1 & 3 should be returned as they have minimum value of _type (2017-01-01).

This can easily be done on per id basis (by querying for min available type for a given id), but that'd be too expensive as the given id list is in range of thousands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query would do what i need:

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "OpID": [id_list]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "OpID",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "least_type": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [{
              "as_of": {
                "order": "asc"
              }
            }
              ],
              "_source": {
                "includes": ["as_of", "OpID"]
              },
              "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Explanation: The bool filter filters out the documents with the given ID list. The aggregation part gives top 1 document found after arranging documents in order of the given field (as_of in this case). The meaning of _source remains the same here.

The above solution worked for me as i had a field **as_of** which is of date type and had the copy of the value stored in **_type**. The above aggregation isn't possible on the field **_type**